# Prove $F_n(z)=\frac1{2i}\left(\left(1+\frac{iz}n\right)^n-\left(1-\frac{iz}n\right)^n\right)...$

Tags: analysis, products

In my textbook there is a proof for the following

> If $n=2m+1$ with $m\in\mathbb N$, then we can write
>   $$F_n(z)=\frac1{2i}\left(\left(1+\frac{iz}n\right)^n-\left(1-\frac{iz}n\right)^n\right)=z\prod_{k=1}^m\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2\tan^2(k\pi/n)}\right)$$

In proof we have found $2m+1=n$ distinct roots $z_k$ of $F_n(z)$ where
$$z_k=n\tan\left(\frac{k\pi}n\right)$$
and $z_{-m}<z_{-m+1}<...<z_{-1}<z_0<z_1<...<z_{m-1}<z_m$, $z_{-k}=-z_k,z_0=0$
so
$$F_n(z)=z\prod_{k=1}^m(z^2-z_k^2)=z\prod_{k=1}^m\left(z^2-n^2\tan^2(\frac{k\pi}n)\right)$$
Now author says "Factoring out $-n^2\tan^2(k\pi/n)$ terms and gathering them all into one constant we can conclude that
$$F_n(z)=az\prod_{k=1}^m\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2\tan^2(k\pi/n)}\right)$$
for some constant $a$." Then author says  $F_n(z)=\frac1{2i}\left(\left(1+\frac{iz}n\right)^n-\left(1-\frac{iz}n\right)^n\right)$ implies that $a=1$. How? Is $a=\prod_{k=1}^m(-n^2\tan^2(k\pi/n))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{align}
F_n(z) &= \frac{1}{2i}\left(\left(1 + \frac{iz}{n}\right)^n - \left(1-\frac{iz}{n}\right)^n\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2i}\left(\left(1 + iz + O(z^2)\right) - \left(1 - iz+ O(z^2)\right)\right)\\
&= z + O(z^2).
\end{align}$$

The coefficient of $z$ on the left is $1$, and on the right in the last formula, the coefficient is $a$.

However, the formula

$$F_n(z) = z\prod_{k=1}^m (z^2-z_k^2)$$

is not correct, there's a constant factor missing. The coefficient of $z^n$ on the right is $1$, but on the left it is

$$\frac{1}{2i}\left(\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^n - \left(\frac{-i}{n}\right)^n\right) = \frac{1}{2in^n}\left(i^{2m+1} - (-i)^{2m+1}\right) = \frac{2i^{2m+1}}{2in^n} = \frac{(-1)^m}{n^n}.$$

So we have

$$\frac{1}{2i}\left(\left(1 + \frac{iz}{n}\right)^n - \left(1 - \frac{iz}{n}\right)^n\right) = \frac{(-1)^m}{n^n}z\prod_{k=1}^m \left(z^2-n^2\tan^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)\right),$$

since both sides are polynomials of degree $n$ with the same zeros and the same leading coefficient. Now factoring out the $-n^2\tan^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)$ leads to

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2i}\left(\left(1 + \frac{iz}{n}\right)^n - \left(1 - \frac{iz}{n}\right)^n\right) &= \frac{(-1)^m}{n^n}\prod_{k=1}^m \left(-n^2\tan^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)\right)z \prod_{k=1}^m \left(1 - \frac{z^2}{n^2\tan^2\frac{k\pi}{n}}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\prod_{k=1}^m \tan^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)\cdot z\prod_{k=1}^m \left(1 - \frac{z^2}{n^2\tan^2\frac{k\pi}{n}}\right),
\end{align}$$

and comparing the coefficient of $z$, which is $1$ on the left and

$$\frac{1}{n}\prod_{k=1}^m \tan^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)$$

on the right proves

$$\prod_{k=1}^m \tan \left(\frac{k\pi}{2m+1}\right) = \sqrt{2m+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks. So $a=\prod_{k=1}^m(-n^2\tan^2(k\pi/n))=1$?

Comment: That follows from the identity then. You know you have $F_n(z) = az\prod\cdots$, and one nonzero coefficient suffices to determine $a$.

Comment: But for example for $m=1$, $\prod_{k=1}^1(-3^2\tan^2(k\pi/3))=-27\neq1$?!!!

Comment: Uh, that's because you don't have $F_n(z) = z \prod_{k=1}^m (z^2-z_k^2)$. The coefficient of $z^n$ in $F_n(z)$ is $\frac{(-1)^m}{n^n}$, so you get $$F_n(z) = \frac{(-1)^m}{n^n}z\prod_{k=1}^m (z^2-z_k^2),$$ and if you factor out the $z_k^2$, that cancels the constant factor to reach the overall identity $$F_n(z) = z \prod_{k=1}^m \left(1 - \frac{z^2}{n^2\tan\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)}\right).$$ Sorry, should have spotted that yesterday, but I only looked at the last formula.

Comment: Hence my book's formula is true if $$\prod_{k=1}^m(-n^2\tan^2(k\pi/n))=\frac{n^n}{(-1)^m}.$$ For $m=1,2$ this is true and for $m\ge3$ is probably true.

Comment: This formula _proves_ the identity of the tangent product, see the updated answer.

Comment: I thought the identity of tangent product implies my book's formula. I now got it. Thanks very much.